# I'm singing a song, can you follow along?

Tags: knowledge, music, graph-theory

What song am I singing?

I apologize for the resolution. If you open the image itself in a new tab you can magnify to get a better look at the words.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> Broken Back - "Excuses". [Lyrics here](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/brokenback/excuses.html).

I didn't know this song, but my solution method was

> to search the diagram for some reasonably rare combination of words (not things like "I will") which was uniquely determined (not the same word having the option to be followed by several others). Down at the bottom we've got "are silently blasting in", which was enough to find the right song.